# Solr schema changes aren't picked up unless Solr is stopped for 3+ seconds

Tags: apache, solr

When I make a change to my Solr (3.4) schema and then restart the process, my changes aren't immediately found. I have to stop the server, wait a few seconds (past when `ps aux` shows the Java process has terminated), and then start it again. Why is this?

Comment: What container/server are you running Solr within?

Answer (score 8):

Schema changes require the solr server to be restarted because the schema is loaded into memory. The [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_rebuild_my_index_from_scratch_if_I_change_my_schema.3F) has some more information on schema changes. There is, however, a way around this. If you run Solr in a [multi-core](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) environment you can dynamically Create, Reload, Rename, Load, and Swap cores on the fly.

A good option for you might be to move your Solr core to the Multi-core directory and start Solr in the multi-core home. Then, when you need to make a schema change, create a new core with the new schema, index your content in the background, then swap your primary core with your new core.

Best of luck to you!

Comment: what about updates/writes in the old one after the full import of the new one and before the swap?

Answer (score -2):

Your browser may be displaying a cached result. I've found that using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in my browser to [force it to refresh without using the cache](https://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome) worked for me after reloading the solr config.